# Implementing "nested" properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, castle-activerecord, complextype

Edit:
looks like this is called a "complex type" in Entity Framework, and I see how I would be able to set the name on columns for having once complex type contained in a class, but I don't know how/if you can do it with multiple of the same complex type contained in the class.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2010/07/26/ef4-complex-type.aspx

[EntityFramework 4.1 Code First incorrectly names complex type column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030390/entityframework-4-1-code-first-incorrectly-names-complex-type-column-names)

---

Since Castle ActiveRecord has been [sunset](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/castle-project-devel/W7hK1WlBpTk), I am moving over to Entity Framework 5, however I don't know how to accomplish the "nested property" concept that Activerecord had:

http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.Mappings.ashx#Nested_5

http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Nested%20data%20%28NHibernate%20components%29&NS=Active%20Record&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

I've done my googling, but I'm not sure that "nested" is the proper terminology for this concept in EF, if it even exists.  Here are my tables and classes that I had in Castle ActiveRecord, can someone please provide the EF terminology for this and how it can be accomplished:

The Address property on AmaStatementEntity marked with `<Nested(ColumnPrefix:="FL")))>` maps to the database columns FLStreet, FLSuite, FLCity, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AMA](
--other columns not necessary to discussion removed
    [AMAId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FLStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLSuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLCity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLCountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FLState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYAStreet] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYASuite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYACity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYAZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYACountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PYAState] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AMA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AMAId] ASC
))
```

---

```
    Public Class AmaStatementEntity

        Public Sub New()
            _amaId = Guid.NewGuid
        End Sub
'Other properties not relavent to discussion removed

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="FL")))>
        Public Property FacilityLocation() As AddressEntity

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="BA"))>
        Public Property BillingAddress() As AddressEntity

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="PA"))>
        Public Property PatientAddress() As AddressEntity

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="IA"))>
        Public Property InsuredAddress() As AddressEntity

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="EA"))>
        Public Property EmployerAddress() As AddressEntity

        <Nested(ColumnPrefix:="PYA"))>
        Public Property PayorAddress() As AddressEntity

        Public Property AMAId() As Guid
    End Class
```

---

```
Public Class AddressEntity
    Public Property Street() As String
    Public Property Suite() As String
    Public Property City() As String
    Public Property State() As String
    Public Property ZipCode() As String
    Public Property Country() As String
    Public Property AddressId() As Guid
End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Reuse Complex Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931341/entity-framework-reuse-complex-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I found the correct terminology I was able to find the answer:

[Entity Framework - Reuse Complex Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931341/entity-framework-reuse-complex-type)

for my specific scenario this is how you would do it (example shows mapping of one of the comlex type references):

```
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<AddressEntity>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().ToTable("vAMA");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().HasKey(a => a.AMAId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.Street).HasColumnName("FLStreet");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.Suite).HasColumnName("FLSuite");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.City).HasColumnName("FLCity");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.ZipCode).HasColumnName("FLZipCode");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.Country).HasColumnName("FLCountry");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AmaStatementEntity>().Property(a => a.FacilityLocation.State).HasColumnName("FLState");
```